# Where can I find a list of all error codes and messages for firebase authentication API

Tags: javascript, error-handling, firebase, firebase-authentication

To handle all possible `auth/` errors Firebase can return to a somehow invalid login I am in search for a full list of all `auth/` errors.

I could find such a list for iOS using Swift but not for the Web API, neither in the old nor in the new documentation.

Does anybody know a resource where all `auth/` errors of the web API are listed? Or is such a list not needed since my approach for error handling is not set up nicely?

---

sample snippet:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(account.mail, account.password).catch(function(error) {
                // TODO: Notify user about error
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorCode)
                console.log(errorMessage)
                if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                    console.log('Mail in use')
                    $state.go('register.mail_in_use')
                }
            });
```

Comment: This has been requested before, so I added your vote to that. But there currently is no such list. Then again, it should be much work to scrape the list from this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### Update 2022:

You can find an [official list of error codes in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes).

---

#### Original answer:

I extracted this from the `firebase-auth.js` file from the [minified CDN files](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-auth.js).
The keys are being added to `auth/` and the values are the default error messages. I hope this helps, but I also hope that a better solution will come up.

You can also have a look at the TypeScript sources [[master]](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/core/errors.ts) [[permalink 08/2023]](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/43e402fb49a081a59729290627c7b20099ca46a4/packages/auth/src/core/errors.ts). These files contain helpful enumerations and constants. However, they are marked as private and protected.

```js
authErrors = {
    "admin-restricted-operation": "This operation is restricted to administrators only.",
    "argument-error": "",
    "app-not-authorized": "This app, identified by the domain where it's hosted, is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the provided API key. Review your key configuration in the Google API console.",
    "app-not-installed": "The requested mobile application corresponding to the identifier (Android package name or iOS bundle ID) provided is not installed on this device.",
    "captcha-check-failed": "The reCAPTCHA response token provided is either invalid, expired, already used or the domain associated with it does not match the list of whitelisted domains.",
    "code-expired": "The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.",
    "cordova-not-ready": "Cordova framework is not ready.",
    "cors-unsupported": "This browser is not supported.",
    "credential-already-in-use": "This credential is already associated with a different user account.",
    "custom-token-mismatch": "The custom token corresponds to a different audience.",
    "requires-recent-login": "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.",
    "dynamic-link-not-activated": "Please activate Dynamic Links in the Firebase Console and agree to the terms and conditions.",
    "email-change-needs-verification": "Multi-factor users must always have a verified email.",
    "email-already-in-use": "The email address is already in use by another account.",
    "expired-action-code": "The action code has expired. ",
    "cancelled-popup-request": "This operation has been cancelled due to another conflicting popup being opened.",
    "internal-error": "An internal error has occurred.",
    "invalid-app-credential": "The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.",
    "invalid-app-id": "The mobile app identifier is not registed for the current project.",
    "invalid-user-token": "This user's credential isn't valid for this project. This can happen if the user's token has been tampered with, or if the user isn't for the project associated with this API key.",
    "invalid-auth-event": "An internal error has occurred.",
    "invalid-verification-code": "The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code sms and be sure use the verification code provided by the user.",
    "invalid-continue-uri": "The continue URL provided in the request is invalid.",
    "invalid-cordova-configuration": "The following Cordova plugins must be installed to enable OAuth sign-in: cordova-plugin-buildinfo, cordova-universal-links-plugin, cordova-plugin-browsertab, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and cordova-plugin-customurlscheme.",
    "invalid-custom-token": "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.",
    "invalid-dynamic-link-domain": "The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project.",
    "invalid-email": "The email address is badly formatted.",
    "invalid-api-key": "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.",
    "invalid-cert-hash": "The SHA-1 certificate hash provided is invalid.",
    "invalid-credential": "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.",
    "invalid-message-payload": "The email template corresponding to this action contains invalid characters in its message. Please fix by going to the Auth email templates section in the Firebase Console.",
    "invalid-multi-factor-session": "The request does not contain a valid proof of first factor successful sign-in.",
    "invalid-oauth-provider": "EmailAuthProvider is not supported for this operation. This operation only supports OAuth providers.",
    "invalid-oauth-client-id": "The OAuth client ID provided is either invalid or does not match the specified API key.",
    "unauthorized-domain": "This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.",
    "invalid-action-code": "The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.",
    "wrong-password": "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.",
    "invalid-persistence-type": "The specified persistence type is invalid. It can only be local, session or none.",
    "invalid-phone-number": "The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code].",
    "invalid-provider-id": "The specified provider ID is invalid.",
    "invalid-recipient-email": "The email corresponding to this action failed to send as the provided recipient email address is invalid.",
    "invalid-sender": "The email template corresponding to this action contains an invalid sender email or name. Please fix by going to the Auth email templates section in the Firebase Console.",
    "invalid-verification-id": "The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.",
    "invalid-tenant-id": "The Auth instance's tenant ID is invalid.",
    "multi-factor-info-not-found": "The user does not have a second factor matching the identifier provided.",
    "multi-factor-auth-required": "Proof of ownership of a second factor is required to complete sign-in.",
    "missing-android-pkg-name": "An Android Package Name must be provided if the Android App is required to be installed.",
    "auth-domain-config-required": "Be sure to include authDomain when calling firebase.initializeApp(), by following the instructions in the Firebase console.",
    "missing-app-credential": "The phone verification request is missing an application verifier assertion. A reCAPTCHA response token needs to be provided.",
    "missing-verification-code": "The phone auth credential was created with an empty SMS verification code.",
    "missing-continue-uri": "A continue URL must be provided in the request.",
    "missing-iframe-start": "An internal error has occurred.",
    "missing-ios-bundle-id": "An iOS Bundle ID must be provided if an App Store ID is provided.",
    "missing-multi-factor-info": "No second factor identifier is provided.",
    "missing-multi-factor-session": "The request is missing proof of first factor successful sign-in.",
    "missing-or-invalid-nonce": "The request does not contain a valid nonce. This can occur if the SHA-256 hash of the provided raw nonce does not match the hashed nonce in the ID token payload.",
    "missing-phone-number": "To send verification codes, provide a phone number for the recipient.",
    "missing-verification-id": "The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID.",
    "app-deleted": "This instance of FirebaseApp has been deleted.",
    "account-exists-with-different-credential": "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.",
    "network-request-failed": "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.",
    "no-auth-event": "An internal error has occurred.",
    "no-such-provider": "User was not linked to an account with the given provider.",
    "null-user": "A null user object was provided as the argument for an operation which requires a non-null user object.",
    "operation-not-allowed": "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.",
    "operation-not-supported-in-this-environment": 'This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.',
    "popup-blocked": "Unable to establish a connection with the popup. It may have been blocked by the browser.",
    "popup-closed-by-user": "The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation.",
    "provider-already-linked": "User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider.",
    "quota-exceeded": "The project's quota for this operation has been exceeded.",
    "redirect-cancelled-by-user": "The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing.",
    "redirect-operation-pending": "A redirect sign-in operation is already pending.",
    "rejected-credential": "The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials.",
    "second-factor-already-in-use": "The second factor is already enrolled on this account.",
    "maximum-second-factor-count-exceeded": "The maximum allowed number of second factors on a user has been exceeded.",
    "tenant-id-mismatch": "The provided tenant ID does not match the Auth instance's tenant ID",
    timeout: "The operation has timed out.",
    "user-token-expired": "The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.",
    "too-many-requests": "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.",
    "unauthorized-continue-uri": "The domain of the continue URL is not whitelisted.  Please whitelist the domain in the Firebase console.",
    "unsupported-first-factor": "Enrolling a second factor or signing in with a multi-factor account requires sign-in with a supported first factor.",
    "unsupported-persistence-type": "The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.",
    "unsupported-tenant-operation": "This operation is not supported in a multi-tenant context.",
    "unverified-email": "The operation requires a verified email.",
    "user-cancelled": "The user did not grant your application the permissions it requested.",
    "user-not-found": "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.",
    "user-disabled": "The user account has been disabled by an administrator.",
    "user-mismatch": "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.",
    "user-signed-out": "",
    "weak-password": "The password must be 6 characters long or more.",
    "web-storage-unsupported": "This browser is not supported or 3rd party cookies and data may be disabled."
}
```

Items last updated: October 2020

Comment: I would definitely not recommend showing these error message to the user. Most of These error messages are not very user-friendly. I'm seeing a lot of red flags here in terms of UX.

Comment: @JohnMiller the goal of this question and answer is to translate/replace these error messages with different messages, for UX/Communication and i18n reasons.

Comment: I created a helper function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998086/4056146).

Comment: Yes, typescript sources, the actual source code is the most helpful answer. Here is the updated source URL, but for the master branch (instead of the commit-linked one given): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/core/errors.ts

Answer (score 15):

We've translated this to portuguese in case anyone needs in the future.

```
    Pf = { "argument-error": "",
"app-not-authorized": "Este aplicativo, identificado pelo domínio onde está hospedado, não está autorizado a usar Firebase Authentication com a chave API fornecida.",
"app-not-installed": "A aplicação móvel solicitada correspondente ao identificador (nome do pacote Android ou ID do pacote iOS) fornecido não está instalada neste dispositivo.",
"captcha-check-failed": "",
"code-expired": "",
"cordova-not-ready": "O framework Cordova não está pronto.",
"cors-unsupported": "Este navegador não é suportado.",
"credential-already-in-use": "Esta credencial já está associada a uma conta de usuário diferente.",
"custom-token-mismatch": "O token personalizado corresponde a um público diferente.",
"requires-recent-login": "Esta operação é sensível e requer autenticação recente. Faça o login novamente antes de tentar novamente esta solicitação.",
"dynamic-link-not-activated": "Ative os links dinâmicos no Firebase Console e concorde com os termos e condições.",
"email-already-in-use": "O endereço de e-mail já está em uso por outra conta.",
"expired-action-code": "O código de ação expirou.",
"cancelled-popup-request": "Esta operação foi cancelada devido a outro popup conflitante sendo aberto.",
"internal-error": "Ocorreu um erro interno.",
"invalid-app-credential": "",
"invalid-app-id": "O identificador do aplicativo móvel não está registrado para o projeto atual.",
"invalid-user-token": "A credencial do usuário não é mais válida. O usuário deve entrar novamente",
"invalid-auth-event": "Ocorreu um erro interno",
"invalid-verification-code": "",
"invalid-cordova-configuration": "Os seguintes plugins Cordova devem ser instalados para habilitar o OAuth sign-in: cordova-plugin-buildinfo, cordova-universal-links-plugin, cordova-plugin-browsertab, cordova-plugin-inappflugin-inapbrowser e cordova-plugin-customurlscheme",
"invalid-custom-token": "O formato de token personalizado está incorreto. Por favor, verifique a documentação.",
"invalid-email": "O endereço de e-mail está mal formatado.",
"invalid-api-key": "Sua chave API é inválida, por favor, verifique se você a copiou corretamente.",
"invalid-credential": "A credencial automática fornecida está mal formatada ou expirou.",
"invalid-message-payload": "O modelo de e-mail correspondente a esta ação contém caracteres inválidos em sua mensagem. Por favor, corrija indo para a seção Auth email templates no Firebase Console.",
"invalid-oauth-provider": "EmailAuthProvider não é suportado para esta operação. Esta operação suporta apenas provedores OAuth.",
"unauthorized-domain": "Este domínio não é autorizado para operações OAuth para o seu projeto Firebase. Edite a lista de domínios autorizados do console do Firebase.",
"invalid-action-code": "O código de ação é inválido. Isto pode acontecer se o código estiver mal formado, expirar ou já tiver sido usado.",
"wrong-password": "A senha é inválida ou o usuário não tem uma senha.",
"invalid-identifier-number": "",
"invalid-recipient-email": "O e-mail correspondente a esta ação não enviou como o endereço de e-mail do destinatário fornecido é inválido.",
"invalid-sender": "O modelo de e-mail correspondente a esta ação contém um e-mail ou nome do remetente inválido. Por favor, corrija indo para a seção Auth email templates no Firebase Console.",
"invalid-verification-id": "",
"missing-iframe-start": "Ocorreu um erro interno.",
"auth-domain-config-required": "Certifique-se de incluir authDomain ao chamar o Firebase. initializeApp(), seguindo as instruções no console do Firebase.",
"missing-app-credential": "",
"missing-verification-code": "",
"missing-identifier-number": "",
"missing-verification-id": "",
"app-deleted": "Esta instância do FirebaseApp foi excluída.",
"account-exists-with-different-credential": "Já existe uma conta com o mesmo endereço de e-mail, mas com credenciais de login diferentes.",
"network-request-failed": "Ocorreu um erro na rede (como timeout, conexão interrompida ou host inalcançável).",
"no-auth-event": "Ocorreu um erro interno.",
"no-such-provider": "O usuário não foi vinculado a uma conta com o provedor fornecido.",
"operation-not-allowed": "O provedor fornecido está desabilitado para este projeto Firebase. Habilite-o no console do Firebase, na aba método de login da seção Auth.",
"operation-not-supported-in-this-environment": "Esta operação não é suportada no ambiente em que esta aplicação está rodando. \\O "location.protocol" deve ser http, https ou chrome-extension e o armazenamento web deve estar habilitado.",
"popup-blocked": "Incapaz de estabelecer uma conexão com o popup. Pode ter sido bloqueada pelo navegador.",
"popup-closed-by-user": "O popup foi fechado pelo usuário antes de finalizar a operação",
"provider-already-linked": "O usuário só pode ser vinculado a uma identidade para o provedor dado",
"quota-exceeded": "",
"redirect-cancelled-by-user": "A operação de redirecionamento foi cancelada pelo usuário antes de finalizar",
"redirect-operation-pending": "Uma operação de redirecionamento de login já está pendente",
"timeout": "A operação foi expirada",
"user-token-expired": "A credencial do usuário não é mais válida. O usuário deve fazer o login novamente.",
"too-many-requests": "Bloqueamos todas as solicitações deste dispositivo devido a atividade incomum. Tente novamente mais tarde.",
"user-cancelled": "O usuário não concedeu a sua solicitação as permissões que solicitou.",
"user-not-found": "Não há nenhum registro de usuário correspondente a este identificador. O usuário pode ter sido excluído.",
"user-disabled": "A conta do usuário foi desabilitada por um administrador.",
"user-mismatch": "As credenciais fornecidas não correspondem ao usuário previamente cadastrado.",
"user-signed-out": "",
"weak-password": "A senha deve ter 6 caracteres ou mais.",
"web-storage-unsupported": "Este navegador não é suportado ou cookies e dados de terceiros podem ser desabilitados."
}
```

Comment: Hey friend, you are a friend!

Answer (score 11):

The complete [list of authentication answers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes) can now also be found in the Firebase documentation, so I recommend checking there for the latest.

Answer (score 6):

In case you need an updated list to translate here it is (from https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-auth.js):

```
{
    "auth/wrong-password": "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.",
    "auth/claims-too-large": "The claims payload provided to setCustomUserClaims() exceeds the maximum allowed size of 1000 bytes.",
    "auth/email-already-exists": "The provided email is already in use by an existing user. Each user must have a unique email.",
    "auth/id-token-expired": "The provided Firebase ID token is expired.",
    "auth/id-token-revoked": "The Firebase ID token has been revoked.",
    "auth/insufficient-permission": "The credential used to initialize the Admin SDK has insufficient permission to access the requested Authentication resource. Refer to Set up a Firebase project for documentation on how to generate a credential with appropriate permissions and use it to authenticate the Admin SDKs.",
    "auth/invalid-argument": "An invalid argument was provided to an Authentication method. The error message should contain additional information.",
    "auth/invalid-claims": "The custom claim attributes provided to setCustomUserClaims() are invalid.",
    "auth/invalid-creation-time": "The creation time must be a valid UTC date string.",
    "auth/invalid-disabled-field": "The provided value for the disabled user property is invalid. It must be a boolean.",
    "auth/invalid-display-name": "The provided value for the displayName user property is invalid. It must be a non-empty string.",
    "auth/invalid-email-verified": "The provided value for the emailVerified user property is invalid. It must be a boolean.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-algorithm": "The hash algorithm must match one of the strings in the list of supported algorithms.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-block-size": "The hash block size must be a valid number.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-derived-key-length": "The hash derived key length must be a valid number.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-key": "The hash key must a valid byte buffer.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-memory-cost": "The hash memory cost must be a valid number.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-parallelization": "The hash parallelization must be a valid number.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-rounds": "The hash rounds must be a valid number.",
    "auth/invalid-hash-salt-separator": "The hashing algorithm salt separator field must be a valid byte buffer.",
    "auth/invalid-id-token": "The provided ID token is not a valid Firebase ID token.",
    "auth/invalid-last-sign-in-time": "The last sign-in time must be a valid UTC date string.",
    "auth/invalid-page-token": "The provided next page token in listUsers() is invalid. It must be a valid non-empty string.",
    "auth/invalid-password": "The provided value for the password user property is invalid. It must be a string with at least six characters.",
    "auth/invalid-password-hash": "The password hash must be a valid byte buffer.",
    "auth/invalid-password-salt": "The password salt must be a valid byte buffer",
    "auth/invalid-photo-url": "The provided value for the photoURL user property is invalid. It must be a string URL.",
    "auth/invalid-provider-data": "The providerData must be a valid array of UserInfo objects.",
    "auth/invalid-oauth-responsetype": "Only exactly one OAuth responseType should be set to true.",
    "auth/invalid-session-cookie-duration": "The session cookie duration must be a valid number in milliseconds between 5 minutes and 2 weeks.",
    "auth/invalid-uid": "The provided uid must be a non-empty string with at most 128 characters.",
    "auth/invalid-user-import": "The user record to import is invalid.",
    "auth/maximum-user-count-exceeded": "The maximum allowed number of users to import has been exceeded.",
    "auth/missing-hash-algorithm": "Importing users with password hashes requires that the hashing algorithm and its parameters be provided.",
    "auth/missing-uid": "A uid identifier is required for the current operation.",
    "auth/missing-oauth-client-secret": "The OAuth configuration client secret is required to enable OIDC code flow.",
    "auth/phone-number-already-exists": "The provided phoneNumber is already in use by an existing user. Each user must have a unique phoneNumber.",
    "auth/project-not-found": "No Firebase project was found for the credential used to initialize the Admin SDKs. Refer to Set up a Firebase project for documentation on how to generate a credential for your project and use it to authenticate the Admin SDKs.",
    "auth/reserved-claims": "One or more custom user claims provided to setCustomUserClaims() are reserved. For example, OIDC specific claims such as (sub, iat, iss, exp, aud, auth_time, etc) should not be used as keys for custom claims.",
    "auth/session-cookie-expired": "The provided Firebase session cookie is expired.",
    "auth/session-cookie-revoked": "The Firebase session cookie has been revoked.",
    "auth/uid-already-exists": "The provided uid is already in use by an existing user. Each user must have a unique uid.",
    "auth/admin-restricted-operation": "This operation is restricted to administrators only.",
    "auth/app-not-authorized": "This app, identified by the domain where it's hosted, is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the provided API key. Review your key configuration in the Google API console.",
    "auth/app-not-installed": "The requested mobile application corresponding to the identifier (Android package name or iOS bundle ID) provided is not installed on this device.",
    "auth/captcha-check-failed": "The reCAPTCHA response token provided is either invalid, expired, already used or the domain associated with it does not match the list of whitelisted domains.",
    "auth/code-expired": "The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.",
    "auth/cordova-not-ready": "Cordova framework is not ready.",
    "auth/cors-unsupported": "This browser is not supported.",
    "auth/credential-already-in-use": "This credential is already associated with a different user account.",
    "auth/custom-token-mismatch": "The custom token corresponds to a different audience.",
    "auth/requires-recent-login": "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.",
    "auth/dependent-sdk-initialized-before-auth": "Another Firebase SDK was initialized and is trying to use Auth before Auth is initialized. Please be sure to call `initializeAuth` or `getAuth` before starting any other Firebase SDK.",
    "auth/dynamic-link-not-activated": "Please activate Dynamic Links in the Firebase Console and agree to the terms and conditions.",
    "auth/email-change-needs-verification": "Multi-factor users must always have a verified email.",
    "auth/email-already-in-use": "The email address is already in use by another account.",
    "auth/emulator-config-failed": "Auth instance has already been used to make a network call. Auth can no longer be configured to use the emulator. Try calling 'connectAuthEmulator()' sooner.",
    "auth/expired-action-code": "The action code has expired.",
    "auth/cancelled-popup-request": "This operation has been cancelled due to another conflicting popup being opened.",
    "auth/internal-error": "An internal AuthError has occurred.",
    "auth/invalid-app-credential": "The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.",
    "auth/invalid-app-id": "The mobile app identifier is not registed for the current project.",
    "auth/invalid-user-token": "This user's credential isn't valid for this project. This can happen if the user's token has been tampered with, or if the user isn't for the project associated with this API key.",
    "auth/invalid-auth-event": "An internal AuthError has occurred.",
    "auth/invalid-verification-code": "The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code sms and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user.",
    "auth/invalid-continue-uri": "The continue URL provided in the request is invalid.",
    "auth/invalid-cordova-configuration": "The following Cordova plugins must be installed to enable OAuth sign-in: cordova-plugin-buildinfo, cordova-universal-links-plugin, cordova-plugin-browsertab, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and cordova-plugin-customurlscheme.",
    "auth/invalid-custom-token": "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.",
    "auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain": "The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project.",
    "auth/invalid-email": "The email address is badly formatted.",
    "auth/invalid-emulator-scheme": "Emulator URL must start with a valid scheme (http:// or https://).",
    "auth/invalid-api-key": "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.",
    "auth/invalid-cert-hash": "The SHA-1 certificate hash provided is invalid.",
    "auth/invalid-credential": "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.",
    "auth/invalid-message-payload": "The email template corresponding to this action contains invalid characters in its message. Please fix by going to the Auth email templates section in the Firebase Console.",
    "auth/invalid-multi-factor-session": "The request does not contain a valid proof of first factor successful sign-in.",
    "auth/invalid-oauth-provider": "EmailAuthProvider is not supported for this operation. This operation only supports OAuth providers.",
    "auth/invalid-oauth-client-id": "The OAuth client ID provided is either invalid or does not match the specified API key.",
    "auth/unauthorized-domain": "This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.",
    "auth/invalid-action-code": "The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.",
    "auth/invalid-persistence-type": "The specified persistence type is invalid. It can only be local, session or none.",
    "auth/invalid-phone-number": "The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code].",
    "auth/invalid-provider-id": "The specified provider ID is invalid.",
    "auth/invalid-recipient-email": "The email corresponding to this action failed to send as the provided recipient email address is invalid.",
    "auth/invalid-sender": "The email template corresponding to this action contains an invalid sender email or name. Please fix by going to the Auth email templates section in the Firebase Console.",
    "auth/invalid-verification-id": "The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.",
    "auth/invalid-tenant-id": "The Auth instance's tenant ID is invalid.",
    "auth/missing-android-pkg-name": "An Android Package Name must be provided if the Android App is required to be installed.",
    "auth/auth-domain-config-required": "Be sure to include authDomain when calling firebase.initializeApp(), by following the instructions in the Firebase console.",
    "auth/missing-app-credential": "The phone verification request is missing an application verifier assertion. A reCAPTCHA response token needs to be provided.",
    "auth/missing-verification-code": "The phone auth credential was created with an empty SMS verification code.",
    "auth/missing-continue-uri": "A continue URL must be provided in the request.",
    "auth/missing-iframe-start": "An internal AuthError has occurred.",
    "auth/missing-ios-bundle-id": "An iOS Bundle ID must be provided if an App Store ID is provided.",
    "auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce": "The request does not contain a valid nonce. This can occur if the SHA-256 hash of the provided raw nonce does not match the hashed nonce in the ID token payload.",
    "auth/missing-multi-factor-info": "No second factor identifier is provided.",
    "auth/missing-multi-factor-session": "The request is missing proof of first factor successful sign-in.",
    "auth/missing-phone-number": "To send verification codes, provide a phone number for the recipient.",
    "auth/missing-verification-id": "The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID.",
    "auth/app-deleted": "This instance of FirebaseApp has been deleted.",
    "auth/multi-factor-info-not-found": "The user does not have a second factor matching the identifier provided.",
    "auth/multi-factor-auth-required": "Proof of ownership of a second factor is required to complete sign-in.",
    "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential": "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.",
    "auth/network-request-failed": "A network AuthError (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.",
    "auth/no-auth-event": "An internal AuthError has occurred.",
    "auth/no-such-provider": "User was not linked to an account with the given provider.",
    "auth/null-user": "A null user object was provided as the argument for an operation which requires a non-null user object.",
    "auth/operation-not-allowed": "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.",
    "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment": "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. 'location.protocol' must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.",
    "auth/popup-blocked": "Unable to establish a connection with the popup. It may have been blocked by the browser.",
    "auth/popup-closed-by-user": "The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation.",
    "auth/provider-already-linked": "User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider.",
    "auth/quota-exceeded": "The project's quota for this operation has been exceeded.",
    "auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user": "The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing.",
    "auth/redirect-operation-pending": "A redirect sign-in operation is already pending.",
    "auth/rejected-credential": "The request contains malformed or mismatching credentials.",
    "auth/second-factor-already-in-use": "The second factor is already enrolled on this account.",
    "auth/maximum-second-factor-count-exceeded": "The maximum allowed number of second factors on a user has been exceeded.",
    "auth/tenant-id-mismatch": "The provided tenant ID does not match the Auth instance's tenant ID",
    "auth/timeout": "The operation has timed out.",
    "auth/user-token-expired": "The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.",
    "auth/too-many-requests": "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.",
    "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri": "The domain of the continue URL is not whitelisted.  Please whitelist the domain in the Firebase console.",
    "auth/unsupported-first-factor": "Enrolling a second factor or signing in with a multi-factor account requires sign-in with a supported first factor.",
    "auth/unsupported-persistence-type": "The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.",
    "auth/unsupported-tenant-operation": "This operation is not supported in a multi-tenant context.",
    "auth/unverified-email": "The operation requires a verified email.",
    "auth/user-cancelled": "The user did not grant your application the permissions it requested.",
    "auth/user-not-found": "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.",
    "auth/user-disabled": "The user account has been disabled by an administrator.",
    "auth/user-mismatch": "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.",
    "auth/weak-password": "The password must be 6 characters long or more.",
    "auth/web-storage-unsupported": "This browser is not supported or 3rd party cookies and data may be disabled.",
    "auth/already-initialized": "initializeAuth() has already been called with different options. To avoid this error, call initializeAuth() with the same options as when it was originally called, or call getAuth() to return the already initialized instance."
}
```

There are some more error codes:

```
"cancelled": "The operation was cancelled (typically by the caller).",
"unknown": "Unknown error or an error from a different error domain.",
"invalid-argument": "Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from 'failed-precondition'. 'invalid-argument' indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g. an invalid field name).",
"deadline-exceeded": "Deadline expired before operation could complete. For operations that change the state of the system, this error may be returned even if the operation has completed successfully. For example, a successful response from a server could have been delayed long enough for the deadline to expire.",
"not-found": "Some requested document was not found.",
"already-exists": "Some document that we attempted to create already exists.",
"permission-denied": "The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.",
"resource-exhausted": "Some resource has been exhausted, perhaps a per-user quota, or perhaps the entire file system is out of space.",
"failed-precondition": "Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution.",
"aborted": "The operation was aborted, typically due to a concurrency issue like transaction aborts, etc.",
"out-of-range": "Operation was attempted past the valid range.",
"unimplemented": "Operation is not implemented or not supported/enabled.",
"internal": "Internal errors. Means some invariants expected by underlying system has been broken. If you see one of these errors, something is very broken.",
"unavailable": "The service is currently unavailable. This is most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.",
"data-loss": "Unrecoverable data loss or corruption.",
"unauthenticated": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials for the operation."
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this.  Simply alert (or log or toast) the `.message`.

```
  function loginUsername(email,password){
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(value) {
      //Logged in
    }).catch(function(error) {
      toast(error.message,7000);
    });              
  }
```

Comment: That's was my first thought. However, I am in need of application specific translated error messages.

Comment: The problem with that is that the message includes the error code and such like in the string: "NativeFirebaseError: [auth/invalid-phone-number]". So you have to parse it before using it. Also the messages can be very long

Answer (score 1):

Here is some for auth/*:

```json
{
  "auth/admin-restricted-operation": "Admin only operation",
  "auth/argument-error": "Argument error",
  "auth/app-not-authorized": "App not authorized",
  "auth/app-not-installed": "App not installed",
  "auth/captcha-check-failed": "Captcha check failed",
  "auth/code-expired": "Code expired",
  "auth/cordova-not-ready": "Cordova not ready",
  "auth/cors-unsupported": "CORS unsupported",
  "auth/credential-already-in-use": "Credential already in use",
  "auth/custom-token-mismatch": "Credential mismatch",
  "auth/requires-recent-login": "Credential too old, login again",
  "auth/dependent-sdk-initialized-before-auth": "Dependent SDK initialized before Auth",
  "auth/dynamic-link-not-activated": "Dynamic link not activated",
  "auth/email-change-needs-verification": "Email change needs verification",
  "auth/email-already-in-use": "Email already in use",
  "auth/emulator-config-failed": "Emulator config failed",
  "auth/expired-action-code": "Expired action code",
  "auth/cancelled-popup-request": "Expired popup request",
  "auth/internal-error": "Internal error",
  "auth/invalid-api-key": "Invalid API key",
  "auth/invalid-app-credential": "Invalid app credential",
  "auth/invalid-app-id": "Invalid app ID",
  "auth/invalid-user-token": "Invalid Auth",
  "auth/invalid-auth-event": "Invalid auth event",
  "auth/invalid-cert-hash": "Invalid cert hash",
  "auth/invalid-verification-code": "Invalid code",
  "auth/invalid-continue-uri": "Invalid continue URI",
  "auth/invalid-cordova-configuration": "Invalid Cordova configuration",
  "auth/invalid-custom-token": "Invalid custom token",
  "auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain": "Invalid dynamic link domain",
  "auth/invalid-email": "Invalid email",
  "auth/invalid-emulator-scheme": "Invalid emulator scheme",
  "auth/invalid-credential": "Invalid IDP response",
  "auth/invalid-message-payload": "Invalid message payload",
  "auth/invalid-multi-factor-session": "Invalid MFA session",
  "auth/invalid-oauth-client-id": "Invalid OAuth client ID",
  "auth/invalid-oauth-provider": "Invalid OAuth provider",
  "auth/invalid-action-code": "Invalid OOB code",
  "auth/unauthorized-domain": "Invalid origin",
  "auth/wrong-password": "Invalid password",
  "auth/invalid-persistence-type": "Invalid persistence",
  "auth/invalid-phone-number": "Invalid phone number",
  "auth/invalid-provider-id": "Invalid provider ID",
  "auth/invalid-recipient-email": "Invalid recipient email",
  "auth/invalid-sender": "Invalid sender",
  "auth/invalid-verification-id": "Invalid session info",
  "auth/invalid-tenant-id": "Invalid tenant ID",
  "auth/multi-factor-info-not-found": "MFA info not found",
  "auth/multi-factor-auth-required": "MFA required",
  "auth/missing-android-pkg-name": "Missing Android package name",
  "auth/missing-app-credential": "Missing app credential",
  "auth/auth-domain-config-required": "Missing Auth domain",
  "auth/missing-verification-code": "Missing code",
  "auth/missing-continue-uri": "Missing continue URI",
  "auth/missing-iframe-start": "Missing iframe start",
  "auth/missing-ios-bundle-id": "Missing iOS bundle ID",
  "auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce": "Missing or invalid nonce",
  "auth/missing-multi-factor-info": "Missing MFA info",
  "auth/missing-multi-factor-session": "Missing MFA session",
  "auth/missing-phone-number": "Missing phone number",
  "auth/missing-verification-id": "Missing session info",
  "auth/app-deleted": "Module destroyed",
  "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential": "Need confirmation",
  "auth/network-request-failed": "Network request failed",
  "auth/null-user": "Null user",
  "auth/no-auth-event": "No auth event",
  "auth/no-such-provider": "No such provider",
  "auth/operation-not-allowed": "Operation not allowed",
  "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment": "Operation not supported",
  "auth/popup-blocked": "Popup blocked",
  "auth/popup-closed-by-user": "Popup closed by user",
  "auth/provider-already-linked": "Provider already linked",
  "auth/quota-exceeded": "Quota exceeded",
  "auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user": "Redirect cancelled by user",
  "auth/redirect-operation-pending": "Redirect operation pending",
  "auth/rejected-credential": "Rejected credential",
  "auth/second-factor-already-in-use": "Second factor already enrolled",
  "auth/maximum-second-factor-count-exceeded": "Second factor limit exceeded",
  "auth/tenant-id-mismatch": "Tenant ID mismatch",
  "auth/timeout": "Timeout",
  "auth/user-token-expired": "Token expired",
  "auth/too-many-requests": "Too many attempts, try later",
  "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri": "Unauthorized domain",
  "auth/unsupported-first-factor": "Unsupported first factor",
  "auth/unsupported-persistence-type": "Unsupported persistence",
  "auth/unsupported-tenant-operation": "Unsupported tenant operation",
  "auth/unverified-email": "Unverified email",
  "auth/user-cancelled": "User cancelled",
  "auth/user-not-found": "User not found",
  "auth/user-disabled": "User disabled",
  "auth/user-mismatch": "User mismatch",
  "auth/user-signed-out": "User signed out",
  "auth/weak-password": "Weak password",
  "auth/web-storage-unsupported": "Web storage unsupported",
  "auth/already-initialized": "Already initialized",
  "auth/recaptcha-not-enabled": "Recaptcha not enabled",
  "auth/missing-recaptcha-token": "Missing Recaptcha token",
  "auth/invalid-recaptcha-token": "Invalid Recaptcha token",
  "auth/invalid-recaptcha-action": "Invalid Recaptcha action",
  "auth/missing-client-type": "Missing client type",
  "auth/missing-recaptcha-version": "Missing Recaptcha version",
  "auth/invalid-recaptcha-version": "Invalid Recaptcha version",
  "auth/invalid-req-type": "Invalid request type"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another more "user friendly" style. Updated with version "firebase": "9.22.2"

```json
{
  "auth/admin-restricted-operation": "This operation is restricted to administrators.",
  "auth/argument-error": "Invalid arguments provided.",
  "auth/app-not-authorized": "This app is not authorized to use Firebase.",
  "auth/app-not-installed": "This app is not installed on your device.",
  "auth/captcha-check-failed": "Google reCAPTCHA check failed.",
  "auth/code-expired": "The provided code has expired.",
  "auth/cordova-not-ready": "Cordova is not ready.",
  "auth/cors-unsupported": "CORS is not supported by your browser.",
  "auth/credential-already-in-use": "This credential is already associated with another account.",
  "auth/custom-token-mismatch": "The custom token and API key do not match.",
  "auth/requires-recent-login": "Please login again, as your last login was too long ago.",
  "auth/dependent-sdk-initialized-before-auth": "Please initialize the Firebase Auth SDK before other dependent SDKs.",
  "auth/dynamic-link-not-activated": "Dynamic links are not activated.",
  "auth/email-change-needs-verification": "Please verify your new email address.",
  "auth/email-already-in-use": "The email address is already in use.",
  "auth/emulator-config-failed": "Emulator configuration failed.",
  "auth/expired-action-code": "The action code has expired.",
  "auth/cancelled-popup-request": "The popup request has been cancelled.",
  "auth/internal-error": "An internal error has occurred.",
  "auth/invalid-api-key": "The provided API key is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-app-credential": "The app credential is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-app-id": "The app ID is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-user-token": "Invalid user token.",
  "auth/invalid-auth-event": "Invalid authentication event.",
  "auth/invalid-cert-hash": "Invalid certificate hash.",
  "auth/invalid-verification-code": "The provided verification code is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-continue-uri": "The continue URL is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-cordova-configuration": "Invalid Cordova configuration.",
  "auth/invalid-custom-token": "The custom token is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain": "The dynamic link domain is invalid.",
  "auth/invalid-email": "Invalid email address.",
  "auth/invalid-emulator-scheme": "Invalid emulator scheme.",
  "auth/invalid-credential": "Invalid Identity Provider response.",
  "auth/invalid-message-payload": "Invalid message payload.",
  "auth/invalid-multi-factor-session": "Invalid multi-factor authentication session.",
  "auth/invalid-oauth-client-id": "Invalid OAuth client ID.",
  "auth/invalid-oauth-provider": "Invalid OAuth provider.",
  "auth/invalid-action-code": "The reset password action code is invalid.",
  "auth/unauthorized-domain": "Unauthorized domain.",
  "auth/wrong-password": "Incorrect password.",
  "auth/invalid-persistence-type": "Invalid persistence type.",
  "auth/invalid-phone-number": "Invalid phone number.",
  "auth/invalid-provider-id": "Invalid provider ID.",
  "auth/invalid-recipient-email": "Invalid recipient email.",
  "auth/invalid-sender": "Invalid sender.",
  "auth/invalid-verification-id": "Invalid verification ID.",
  "auth/invalid-tenant-id": "Invalid tenant ID.",
  "auth/multi-factor-info-not-found": "Multi-factor authentication information not found.",
  "auth/multi-factor-auth-required": "Multi-factor authentication is required.",
  "auth/missing-android-pkg-name": "Missing Android package name.",
  "auth/missing-app-credential": "Missing app credential.",
  "auth/auth-domain-config-required": "Missing authentication domain configuration.",
  "auth/missing-verification-code": "Missing verification code.",
  "auth/missing-continue-uri": "Missing continue URL.",
  "auth/missing-iframe-start": "Missing iframe start.",
  "auth/missing-ios-bundle-id": "Missing iOS bundle ID.",
  "auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce": "Missing or invalid nonce.",
  "auth/missing-multi-factor-info": "Missing multi-factor authentication information.",
  "auth/missing-multi-factor-session": "Missing multi-factor authentication session.",
  "auth/missing-phone-number": "Missing phone number.",
  "auth/missing-verification-id": "Missing verification ID.",
  "auth/app-deleted": "The authentication module has been deleted.",
  "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential": "An account with this email already exists with a different credential.",
  "auth/network-request-failed": "A network request has failed.",
  "auth/null-user": "No user is currently signed in.",
  "auth/no-auth-event": "No authentication event.",
  "auth/no-such-provider": "No such Identity Provider.",
  "auth/operation-not-allowed": "This operation is not allowed.",
  "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment": "This operation is not supported in your current environment.",
  "auth/popup-blocked": "Popup blocked by the browser.",
  "auth/popup-closed-by-user": "Popup closed by user.",
  "auth/provider-already-linked": "This provider is already linked to your account.",
  "auth/quota-exceeded": "Quota exceeded.",
  "auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user": "Redirect cancelled by user.",
  "auth/redirect-operation-pending": "Redirect operation is pending.",
  "auth/rejected-credential": "Rejected credential.",
  "auth/second-factor-already-in-use": "Second factor authentication method already in use.",
  "auth/maximum-second-factor-count-exceeded": "Maximum number of second factor methods exceeded.",
  "auth/tenant-id-mismatch": "Tenant ID mismatch.",
  "auth/timeout": "A timeout has occurred.",
  "auth/user-token-expired": "User token has expired.",
  "auth/too-many-requests": "Too many attempts. Please try again later.",
  "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri": "Unauthorized continue URL.",
  "auth/unsupported-first-factor": "Unsupported first factor authentication method.",
  "auth/unsupported-persistence-type": "Unsupported persistence type.",
  "auth/unsupported-tenant-operation": "Unsupported tenant operation.",
  "auth/unverified-email": "Unverified email address.",
  "auth/user-cancelled": "User cancelled authentication.",
  "auth/user-not-found": "User not found.",
  "auth/user-disabled": "User account is disabled.",
  "auth/user-mismatch": "User mismatch.",
  "auth/user-signed-out": "User has signed out.",
  "auth/weak-password": "The password is weak.",
  "auth/web-storage-unsupported": "Web storage is unsupported by your browser.",
  "auth/already-initialized": "Firebase Auth has already been initialized.",
  "auth/recaptcha-not-enabled": "Google reCAPTCHA is not enabled.",
  "auth/missing-recaptcha-token": "Missing Google reCAPTCHA token.",
  "auth/invalid-recaptcha-token": "Invalid Google reCAPTCHA token.",
  "auth/invalid-recaptcha-action": "Invalid Google reCAPTCHA action.",
  "auth/missing-client-type": "Missing client type.",
  "auth/missing-recaptcha-version": "Missing Google reCAPTCHA version.",
  "auth/invalid-recaptcha-version": "Invalid Google reCAPTCHA version.",
  "auth/invalid-req-type": "Invalid request type."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in need of an application specific translated error message, here's how I would go about it(using typescript + firebase 9):

```js
import { AuthErrorCodes } from 'firebase/auth'

class InvalidEmailError extends Error {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message)
        this.name = 'InvalidEmailError'
    }
}

export type LoginError = InvalidEmailError | Error

async function loginUsername(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        // some login code...
    } catch(e) {
        if (e instanceof Error) {
            if (e.message.includes(AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_EMAIL) {
               throw new InvalidEmailError('Incorrect email or password')
            } else {
               throw new Error('Something went wrong')
            }
        }
    }
}

// The calling code somehwere
try {
    loginUsername(email, password)
} catch(e) {
    document.body.innerHTML = (e as Error).message
}
```

If you're using vscode, you can `Command + click` or `Ctrl + click` on `AuthErrorCodes` which should navigate you to `auth-public.d.ts`; where you'll be able to see all the available error code firebase provides.