# Firestore error code to human readable message

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I need a way to convert the error code Firestore gives me when it throws on `async` `await` to a human readable message.  What interfaces are exposed that can help me do this?  Example login function:

```js
  async onSubmitLogin(e: any) {
    try {
      const user: UserCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, e.value["Email"], e.value["Password"]);
    } catch (error: any) {
      // show error popup to user
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a utility function in my firestore class to do this.  Possible error codes can be seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes).  I did not go through every error code, but they can all be handled in this manner.

```js
// Firebase
import { AuthErrorCodes } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class FirebaseService {
  private debug: boolean = true;

  constructor() {}

  public getMessageFromCode(error: string): string | undefined {
    let msg: string | undefined = undefined;

    if (error) {
      // convert error to string in case it's not
      error = error.toString();

      // get firestore error code
      // e.x.: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/user-not-found).
      const idx: number = error.indexOf("Firebase: Error ("); // returns -1 when not found
      if (idx != -1) {
        const code: string = error.substring(idx + 17, error.indexOf(")", idx));
        if (this.debug) {
          console.debug(`getMessageFromCode >> code = ${code}`);
        }

        // convert code to a human readable message (some messages can be found here: <https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors?hl=en>)
        switch (code) {
          case AuthErrorCodes.ARGUMENT_ERROR: {
            msg = "Argument error.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN: {
            msg = "Please logout, re-login, and try again.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_PASSWORD: {
            msg = "Incorrect password.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.TOKEN_EXPIRED: {
            msg = "Your token has expired.  Please logout and re-login.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.USER_CANCELLED: {
            msg = "Login process was stopped by you.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.USER_DELETED: {
            msg = "User does not exist.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.USER_DISABLED: {
            msg = "Your account has been disabled.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.USER_MISMATCH: {
            msg = "Credential given does not correspond to you.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.USER_SIGNED_OUT: {
            msg = "You are signed out.  Please re-sign in.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.WEAK_PASSWORD: {
            msg = "Your password is too weak.  It must be at least six characters long.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_EMAIL: {
            msg = "The email address is improperly formatted.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR: {
            msg = "Internal Error.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_API_KEY: {
            msg = "Invalid API key.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL: {
            msg = "Invalid app credential.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_APP_ID: {
            msg = "Invalid app ID.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.INVALID_AUTH: {
            msg = "Invalid user token.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.TIMEOUT: {
            msg = "Authentication timeout.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.UNVERIFIED_EMAIL: {
            msg = "Your email address is not verified.  Please verify it.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.WEB_STORAGE_UNSUPPORTED: {
            msg = "Web storage is unsupported.  Please update or use a different browser.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.ALREADY_INITIALIZED: {
            msg = "Already initialized.";
            break;
          }
          case AuthErrorCodes.TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER: {
            msg = "Access to this account has been temporarily disabled due to many failed login attempts. You can immediately restore it by resetting your password or you can try again later.";
            break;
          }
          default: {
            msg = `Unknown error >> code = ${code}`;
            break;
          }
        }

        // log
        if (this.debug) {
          console.debug(`getMessageFromCode >> msg = ${msg}`);
        }
      }
    }

    return msg;
  }

}
```